# Como hacer una ventana en modo modal

Tags: html, css, modal

hay muchos tutoriales de como hacer una ventana modal en HTML con CSS pero esa ventana modal solo funciona en esa misma página. Yo lo que quiero hacer es que esa ventana modal sea para todo en general, es decir, que si esta abierta mi página de HTML y yo abro por ejemplo, un CMD o la configuración de Windows, mi página de HTML se siga viendo en 1º plano. (Estoy hablando de HTML pero podría ser cualquier otro lenguaje).
Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: ¿Tu has visto ese comportamiento en alguna web?  Pregúntatelo.  Si es así, ¿donde?  Eso suena más a cosa del sistema operativo que a codificación de modales en html.  Sí es cierto que hay una modalidad `Kiosk` de los navegadores que quizás te sirva para algo, pero no es para "modal" sino para la ventana del navegador en si a pantalla completa.

Comment: Realmente también podría ser sin HTML, otra cosa, porque como es más fácil entenderlo pues pensaba que habría algo de ese estilo. Pero queremos solo mostrar un texto en pantalla y que ese texto no se quite aun ejecutando otras aplicaciones.

Comment: Ni idea, eso ya entra dentro del funcionamiento del sistema operativo donde pretendas hacerlo, y no tiene nada que ver ni con HTML, CSS o modales. A nivel de navegador puedes buscar información sobre la modalidad Kiosk y ver cuales lo soportan. Eso te pone el navegador a pantalla completa y no se sale de el facilmente, y mientras se pueden ejecutar cosas por debajo, y segun como puedes llegar a verlas por encima, pero me parece recordar que tampoco era tan facil hacerlo.  Fuera de eso poco te puedo ayudar. Suerte!

Comment: Como te dicen mas arriba nada tiene que ver eso con html. Si estas en windows debes buscar por el lado de la api win32 que es la que se encarga de dibujar las ventanas y dialogos del sistema op. De forma nativa se trabaja con c/c++. Pero puede haber wrappers para otros lenguajes como python, que puede interactuar los librerias de c